# How to build buttons like the ones from netbeans toolbar?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I'm developing a system and I'd like to make buttons with side options into toolbar, but I have no idea how to do it.
I've tried with combo boxes - but I haven't figured out how to insert icons in it, and tried buttons too.

The idea is to do something like this:

[image: netbeans icons]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an ImageIcon to your jComboBox?

```
jComboBox1.addItem(new ImageIcon("image1.png"));
```

Alternatively, you can pass array of ImageIcons to JComboBox constructor:

```
Object[] items =
{
    new ImageIcon("image1.png"),
    new ImageIcon("image2.png"),
    new ImageIcon("image3.png")
};
jComboBox1 = new JComboBox(items);
```

**EDIT:** I'm not sure I get what are you trying to accomplish, but this might be it. First - where you create a form, add:

```
comboBox1.setEditable(true);
comboBox1.setEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor());
```

*MyComboBoxEditor* is a custom class and should look like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxEditor;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyComboBoxEditor extends BasicComboBoxEditor {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public MyComboBoxEditor() {
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image1.png"));
        panel.add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getEditorComponent() {
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Comment: `addItem` method accepts only string as a parameter. So this line may show an error saying like `incompatible types: ImageIcon cannot be converted to String`.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `addItem` accepts generic type as parameter

Comment: I am not sure about it. But after reading [JComboBox.addItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem(E)) your edited may accept i.e. `items`. But I am still confused whether it will display icon in this ComboBox or not.

Comment: Ok, why don't you just try it and see it yourself? Even jLabel can show image, it's not necessarily bound to text value

Comment: But it will create an item with the image. I just want to set the image in the combo box, and when I expand it will be filled only with the items I've already added (or will add).

Comment: @LetíciaTorres take a look at "update" part of answer

Comment: Any luck solving this?